# Swift Array.sort() won't accept closure in shorthand format

Tags: swift, closures

I'm running into a strange issue with the Array.sort() function. It fails to accept a shorthand closure. Xcode complains with the following message when using the shorthand closure: `Cannot invoke 'sort' with an argument list of type '((_, _) -> _)'` But it works with the longer form of the same closure.

```
var names = ["Al", "Mike", "Clint", "Bob"]

// This `sort()` function call fails:
names.sort {
    $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == .OrderedAscending
}

// This `sort()` function call works:
names.sort { (first: String, second: String) in
    return first.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(second) == .OrderedAscending
}
```

To make things extra weird, if I first use the long form of the closure and then sort again using the shorthand form, it works fine!

```
var names = ["Al", "Mike", "Clint", "Bob"]

// Works fine, orders the array alphabetically
names.sort { (first: String, second: String) in
    return first.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(second) == .OrderedAscending
}

// This shorthand version now works as well, reversing the order of the array
names.sort {
    $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == .OrderedDescending
}
```

So, best case scenario, I'm doing something wrong and get to learn something. Worst case, this is just a stupid bug with Xcode or Swift.

Any ideas?

Comment: OK that is super weird and most definitely a compiler bug.  You should [file it](http://bugreport.apple.com/).

Comment: I was expecting it to be a playground thing but the same switch-the-order-and-it-compiles thing happens with `swiftc` too.

Comment: Interesting. If you just stick any kind of reference to `NSComparisonResult` (`let x: NSComparisonResult` would do it) at the top of the file, this also fixes the problem with the first example.  It’s as if the [implicit member expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID394) feature needs “priming” with a more explicit reference to the enum type before it will work. Hence reordering the expressions fixes it.

Comment: `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare` is actually a Foundation method of `NSString`. It seems that the automatic bridging somehow does not work. It suffices to reference any Foundation method before to make that code compile, e.g. `let s = NSString()`.

Comment: @MartinR funny, `let s = NSString()` is enough when compiling with `swiftc` but not in a playground

Comment: You should file a bug at https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Bug report filed an hour or two ago! Thanks for all the feedback with this.

Comment: aaand… it’s fixed in 2.0 released today :)  // @MartinR

Answer (score -1):

as @Martin R pointed out, the root of the problem is, that you're calling a method from NSString on a Swift String type.

this works fine

```
names.sort {
    $0 <= $1
}
```

Comment: Two things:First, Swift String and NSString should be toll-free bridged, so calling an NSString method on a Swift String will work. Or at least it's supposed to. Second, the comparison method you are using, using `<=` to compare two Strings, is not the same as a case insensitive comparison.